# PHP 5.2 and Smarty, Scope issue

Tags: php, html, scope, smarty

I am trying to separate my code into functions to make it more readable.

I made a function to update a field in a database. What I am trying to do is that when they change the username it goes to update Account function then updates the session variable , the smarty var,and the database regarding the name.

Everything gets updated after the form is submitted but the smarty variable and I can't figure out why(i know its something to do with the scope) because if i declare it out of the function it works fine.

All the magic that i need fixed is in the Home portion of the routing section of my code. Thank you for any help :)

code :http://pastebin.com/VdRPz3hc

Comment: ~140 lines of code, can't you provide the relevant code ?

Comment: its all relavent, considering its all the code that is used to create the issue. basically how do you set a smarty variable wrapped in a function(locally) to work globally?

Comment: Furthermore, being grammatically sound, "~140 lines of code and you can't provide the relevant code?" One could have asked for the omitted code that could be helpful to solve the issue. As far as I was concerned that was enough. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I solved the issue, it was indeed a silly scope issue.

Comment: Some users tend to drop hundred lines of code and expect us to debug it, once it was really almost 1000 lines. That's a bit crazy, make it easier for us to help, we're doing if for free. And if I said "Please show the omitted code" you maybe would have posted another tens of lines of code.

Comment: What was the solution? I'm running into a similar issue.